# PHP list() warning case

Tags: php

Reading about list() function you can find such warning in the notes section:

> Warning
>
> list() assigns the values starting with the right-most parameter. If you are using plain variables, you don't have to worry about this. **But if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the list() from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned in the reverse order.**

Can anyone provide code example when reverse order assignment would happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
php> $array = array();

php> list($array[0], $array[1]) = array(1, 2)

php> var_dump($array)
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [0] =>
  int(1)
}
```

So [1] is assigned before [0].

Comment: +1 The effect is subtle: The values are assigned to the specified indices, but the order of the indices is reversed.